# BigQuery - Synchronous RunQuery

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a job in `GoogleBigQuery`, that returns a `JobId` instantly whilst the `Job` continues to run without making the user wait.

From reading the documentation `runQuery` suggests this should be possible.  `maxRetries` has been set as well as a very small `timeoutMs`.

The idea being that the user will get a `JobId` and an alert notifying them the `Job` is being processed and they will receive a further notification when it's complete.

Installed via Composer Version: `google/cloud: ^0.53.0`

Sample code included below.

> **runQuery**
>
> Runs a BigQuery SQL query in a synchronous fashion.
>
> Unless $options.maxRetries is specified, this method will block until the query completes, at which time the result set will be returned.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.53.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=runQuery

```
    $client = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => 'XXXX',
    ]);
    $client->dataset('XXXX');
    if (!$dataset->exists()) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Dataset does not exist'));
    }
    $options = [
            'timeoutMs' => 1000,
            'maxRetries' => 2,
    ];
    $queryJob = $client->queryConfig($sql, $options); //tried options here
    $queryResult = $client->runQuery($queryJob,$options); //and tried options here together and individually
    echo $queryResult->job()->id();
```

Comment: use startQuery() that is asynchronous

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick.